# Android OnTouchListener ACTION_HOLD?

Tags: android, android-view

Here is my code:

```
    mSendButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

               switch(event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Send bluetooth data
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Stop sending
                    break;
                }
                return false;
        }
    });
```

The code is working on down action, but when i hold the button, it only do the sending data once. **I want it to keep sending data while i'm holding the button**, and then stop when i release the button. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Create a while loop that starts when you press down and stops when you lift up

Comment: With a while loop you will block the main UI thread. So you can create a new Thread in ACTION_DOWN that will do the work, and stop it when ACTION_UP

Comment: umm, this maybe a silly question, but i really don't know where to put it

Comment: @DerryPratama The reason you don't understand is because you don't know what the actions mean, you should spend some time reading about APIs you use, so that you can be familiar with what you're doing. Recommended reading is reaching about MotionEvent.

Answer (score 0):

play with something **like while(flag){} loop. when ever event ACTION_DOWN occurs make the flag true that continuously runs the loop asynchronously( run in separate thread) when ACTION_UP make it false** that stops running the loop in the thread.

```
    mSendButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Send bluetooth data
                thread.start();
                flag = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Stop sending
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            return false;
    }
});

//RUN THE BELOW FUNCTION IN A THREAD:
     void funtion(){
         while(flag){
   //enter the code here
         }
     }
```